# How to substitute with basic regex with alternating signs?

Tags: sed

I want to do the following to all of the statements in the file:

Input: `xblahxxblahxxblahblahx`

Output: `<blah><blah><blahblah>`

So far I am thinking of using `sed -i 's/x/</g' something.ucli`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed 's/x\([^x]*\)x/<\1>/g'
```

*Details*:

- `x` - an `x`
- `\([^x]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): zero or more (`*`) chars other than `x` (`[^x]`)
- `x` - an `x`

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/nKI94k):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='xblahxxblahxxblahblahx'
sed 's/x\([^x]*\)x/<\1>/g' <<< "$s"
# => <blah><blah><blahblah>
```

If `x` is a multichar string, e.g.`xyz`, it will be easier with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/xyz(.*?)xyz/<$1>/g'
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/0bN7gM).